# Can there be a race condition between __has_include() and the subsequent #include?

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider the following C++1z code that uses [`__has_include()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include):

```
#if __has_include(<optional>)
#  include <optional>
#  define have_optional 1
#else
#  define have_optional 0
#endif
```

Can there be a race condition between `__has_include(<optional>)` and the subsequent `#include <optional>` or does the standard guarantee a race-free behavior? For example, in an (improbable) situation where the header file gets deleted right after the `__has_include()` check, the `#include` would unexpectedly fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I would argue that it's very much an implementation-specific issue, [this `#include` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) says

> A `__has_include` result of `1` only means that a header or source file with the specified name exists. It does not mean that the header or source file, when included, would not cause an error or would contain anything useful.

So you should not count on a subsequent `#include` directive succeeding.

The above linked reference actually continues the above quote with mentioning that a compiler with both C++14 and C++17 modes could have `__has_include` as an extension of its C++14 mode, with an example of using just `<optional>` could lead to `__has_include(<optional>)` succeeding in C++14 mode but the actual `#include` failing.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. The Standard doesn't really mention much. The last sentence in http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.cond#4 seems to support this.